# Downloading or opening files on iOS / iPad

Tags: office-js

In my excel add-in users need to be able to download and open an xlsx file. On desktop this works fine, but on iPads and iOS the only way I can get the file onto the device is to add the files through itunes.

Is there any way to download files (specifically xlsx) to the device?

Comment: Are this files stored in OneDrive?

Comment: No the files are stored externally and are specific to the user.